# self-training task

Tags: go, concurrency

I need limit running function by maxTasks variable. Can you check my answer and possible to make adjustments.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math/rand"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    maxTasks := 10
    var tasks []func()
    for x := 0; x < 50; x++ {
        fmt.Println("add new task with num ", x)
        tasks = append(tasks, func(x int) func() {
            fmt.Println("create function with ", x)
            return func() {
                worktime := rand.Intn(10)
                time.Sleep(time.Duration(worktime) * time.Second)
                fmt.Println("current task:",x )
                fmt.Println(" with worktime ",worktime)
            }
        }(x))
    }
    //tasks[0]()
    ch := make(chan int, maxTasks)
    for _, task := range tasks {

        go func(t func()) {
            ch <- 1
            t()
            fmt.Println("current task:",len(ch))
            <- ch
        }(task)
    }
    time.Sleep(10000 * time.Second)
}
```

Comment: There's no question here. What you do expect, and what do you get?

Comment: i expect than in the same time will be running only 10 functions

Comment: There is nothing to limit the number of goroutines being created. They'll launch as quickly as possible, then some will wait until they can send `1` to the channel. You haven't shown what isn't working.

Comment: If you want to have "only 10 goroutines active at any time" you may want to use a goroutine pool: https://gobyexample.com/worker-pools

Comment: you should search with keywords like https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgo%5D+pool+worker

Comment: The whole approach here is flawed. Try splitting the task into smaller parts. Create one goroutine that keeps track of the number of tasks, and starts new one when the amount is lower then maxTasks.

Comment: Why approach here is flawed? This icode work correctly. Can you write code and share on go playground

Comment: @Marc they will wait and my jobs will be not running. is it limiting, right? Or will be better limit goroutines (not a task function)?

Comment: I think this previous question is the same: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25306073/always-have-x-number-of-goroutines-running-at-any-time